# How to modify class on an element created by an external javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an embedded script on my website, that's creating a button with a specific class. I display this in two places on my webpage, but want to assign different styling to the button in the two places. My question: is there a way to 'overwrite' the class attribute of an  element which is created by this external script, only in the place where it is displayed?

The code I have control over looks like this:

```
<div class="homepageslide">
    <script src="https://tool.reframeyourclients.com/js/insertfill-z0f1d1db4-41f6-4543-8de1-6d080ae1635b.js" type="text/javascript" id="ryc-insert-script-z0f1d1db4-41f6-4543-8de1-6d080ae1635b" onclick="javascript:ga('send', 'event', 'homepage-slider-grader', 'click');">
    </script>
</div>
```

And on the website it is rendered as:

```
<div class="homepageslide">
    <span id="ryc-fill-button-z0f1d1db4-41f6-4543-8de1-6d080ae1635b" type="button" class="rycfill-btn" style="color: rgb(122, 128, 0); border: 1px solid rgb(175, 183, 0); border-radius: 4px; font-family: Ubuntu-Regular; font-size: 15px;">Start Survey +</span>
    <script src="https://tool.reframeyourclients.com/js/insertfill-z0f1d1db4-41f6-4543-8de1-6d080ae1635b.js" type="text/javascript" id="ryc-insert-script-z0f1d1db4-41f6-4543-8de1-6d080ae1635b">
    </script>
</div>
```

The embedded script creates that  element, for which I want to manipulate the class (remove 'rycfill-btn' and add 'myClass') and optionally remove the style that follows a well. Is this possible / how?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can just use css for the styles, I'd add `rycfill-btn` to your stylesheet instead of swapping the class out - you can remove the style attribute using javascript

Comment: Hi @Darren, I have already defined my styling for the `rycfill-btn` in the stylesheet, but I'm calling the same embedded javascript in two places on my website, one of which I need to display with a different styling - hence wanting to change the class _only_ on that instance of my button. Any tips on how I can use javascript to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. You could just modify the existing class that the script applies to the element to change its appearance. But you mentioned in a comment that you want to edit once instance of the button but not others. You might still be able to do that with the right CSS selector if that button has some special property (eg its always the nth child of its parent). But otherwise you can do it with JavaScript.

Just write a script that runs after the existing script finishes. Then select the target button and remove its existing class and replace it.

```
elements = document.getElementsByClassName('rycfill-btn');
theButton = elements[3]; // or whatever you need to do to get the one you want and ignore the other one
theButton.className = 'myClass'; // This should both add the new class and overwrite the old one
```

Of course, you need some way to differentiate between the button you want to change and the one you don't. If you the you do want to change is made first you can just run the script that modifies the button before its loaded. Otherwise you need to know something about it (eg it will always be the second instance on the page).

You can probably do it more elegantly if you use jQuery or some other DOM manipulation library.

Comment: Thanks @William, this worked! I added `theButton.style = '';` in the script just before `theButton.className = 'readon';` to remove the styling that was being passed on by the script, so now it looks great. Cheers!